# Web Service Async response

Tags: java, api, web-services

Lets say you submitted a request to an API to do something and it returns a response saying I have got your request and  I am working on it. How do you test the final response if it takes 5 mins?

Comment: you can use thread  synchronization. But 5 mint.....is too much time for communication.

Comment: Is it SOAP WS or Restful WS? There are ways to do async communication like https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15523_01/web.1111/e15184/asynch.htm#WSCPT136 in SOAP. Another way is to do polling after every n minutes to check for response. Example write a job to check the response every 5 minutes. If response is not there then check after another n minutes. The second approach is valid for SOAP/Rest WS.

Comment: Thanks guys..its a rest WS..can you provide some code or pseudocode?